# How to create a sub page in same page without leaving the main page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

in the main page, I've have a login button. what I want is: when the user clicks it, it's doesn't take him anywhere, it just shows a login box. Ex. go to medium.com and see what happened when you click 'sign in'
can i do it with html & css only?

Comment: Have you tried out anything to get it done yourself?

Comment: What you are talking about is called a "modal" and its not good idea to try that without JavaScript because it will make the code complex and lengthy . Start with this link and try to figure out how you can modify the modal according to your need https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: You have a better chance of getting help if you show what you have already tried (i.e., as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). There are many ways to do what you ask for. Take, e.g., a look at [Bootstrap modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/).

Comment: Check this out - https://nccfutoblockchain.com. I designed it with login, signup and homepage all on the same page. Do you want something like that?

Answer (score 0):

not really css and html only, but you can make a css class that makes the object dissapear

```
.dissapear {
display:none;
}
```

and then make a function

```
function dissapear(){
element = document.getelementbyid("loginbox")
element.classlist.toggle("dissapear")
}
```

and then in html

```
<div onClick="dissapear();"></div>
<div class="dissapear" id="loginbox">put your login box here </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to show the login box when the login button is clicked I think you want to use **modal**. You can learn more with this keyword.
2. For modal, you need to add some JS code.
3. Below is the code I referenced at [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal) and slightly edited. You will need to adjust the HTML and CSS to fit your needs:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-control {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Login</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="form-control">
      <span class="username-label">username:</span>
      <input name="username" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <span class="password-label">password:</span>
      <input class="password" type="password" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```